# How to minimize battery usage while hatching eggs in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

What's the best way to preserve your battery while hatching eggs in Pokemon Go?
For example, do I need to keep the app open and up front? Are there game or phone settings that affect Pokemon Go battery usage?

I'm using Android 6.

Comment: Definitely not a solution to minimize usage, but get a portable charger? With one of those + a full charge beginning your day, you SHOULD be able to stay afloat.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest settings to reduce the energy consumption are your Location settings:

> ->> Settings ->> Location

[image: Location settings]

> ->> Mode

[image: Mode settings]

Here you can choose battery saving which has quite a big influence. Your battery is saved at performance's charge: When I activated the "battery saving" location setting I noticed some huge latencies when walking around whereas I never faced those issues when I played with the "High Accuracy" option.

I think this option is available since Android 5.0. Correct me if I am wrong.

Another option is in the Application's setting itself:

> ->> Pokemon GO ->> "Pokeball" ->> Settings

[image: Poke GO Settings]

I do not know what this option does exactly but I think it also tries to reduce the accesses of Android's Location service (Also look at this topic: [What does the battery saver do in Pokémon Go?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273030/what-does-the-battery-saver-do-in-pokemongo)).

> **Update June 30, 2016:** This Update removed the In-App Battery Saver for iOS.

Tip:

> Always carry along a charger and hang around nearby sockets :P

Comment: Battery Saver reduces the number of checks for location across both Android and iOS, and it also will disable the screen when you turn the phone upside-down. This will allows you to still get notifications and have your steps count towards egg hatching while keeping the screen off. Note that you can NOT lock the device or close the app if you want either to happen.

Comment: Mine did this without the battery saver mode turned on so is this a dual function, a glitch? I only turned battery saver mode on today and haven't noticed any difference in game play or battery usage. The black screen when turned upside down has happened since install battery saver mode on or not.

Comment: While the battery save mode it is really a good idea, it constantly crashes the app on my device. Whenever I want my device to come out of it, the screen becomes unresponsive to user inputs.

Comment: Regarding battery saver: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273030/what-does-the-battery-saver-do-in-pokemongo

Comment: @Kauzig added this into my post. thx.

Comment: I updated yesterday and on my Android the Battery Saver is still there.

Comment: @Phil yes indeed, seems just to be iOS. As the question is actually about android the edit would be useless so, but I still kept the change.

Answer (score 3):

Best is maybe also download the map in google maps for your area? 
I did this and it seems to improve the battery loss

Comment: Does this also works in ios?

Comment: Pokemon Go does not make use of Google's map database, so it is entirely coincidental in your case.

Comment: @poepje are you sure? Do you have any sources? I have seen people in multiple places suggesting downloading maps although they all might be wrong

Comment: @Templar Though I can't find the same page anymore, I read that one of the main people responsible for creating Google Maps now works for Niantic (Pokemon Go's developer). I'd say he likely used part of the source code for Pokemon Go. I did find another page on the same topic: http://bit.ly/29ZONth

Comment: I can say that I have my local area downloaded in Google Maps, and when I'm sitting around for an hour at a restaurant in my area, the game uses 10-15% battery with the screen on all the time, but this weekend when I was out of state and sitting in the same spot for an hour, it used over 40% of my battery doing the exact same thing

Answer (score 1):

In the battery saving mode, when you hold your phone so that the top faces the ground, the screen goes black with a very dim white pokemon go logo in the middle of the screen so it saves energy. When a wild pokemon jumps out, the screen will notify you and light back up.

Comment: In the battery saving mode, the phone will also disable GPS, and leave you unable to find the player position to locate pokemon, to begin with.

Comment: They've described the game's power saver, not the phone power saver. The in-game power saver works as conner described (assuming you don't encounter bugs, as some people have).