# What does the battery saver do in PokemonGo?

Tags: pokemon-go

Like the title asks, will this actually save battery, or will it shut off features after a certain amount of time?

Note: this is the iPhone version.

[image]

Comment: Pokémon Go used Battery Drain.  It's super effective!

Comment: How do you even access this screen

Comment: @Scribblenautical on the top right inside the menu, it says *settings*. Tap the gear icon beside it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[8/8/2016](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/update-080816/) update has added the Battery Saver backed into the iOS devices

> Resolved issues with the battery saver mode on iOS and re-enabled the feature

---

In the [3/8/2016](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/launch-latam/) update for iOS, the Battery Feature has been removed for the time being. The feature is still available for Android devices

> We have been hearing the feedback loud and clear about the removal of the Battery Saver mode on iOS devices. We had removed this feature as several users were experiencing it to be buggy, but we are fairly confident that a fix for this should roll out within the next several days.

---

[Support PokemonGo - Settings](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221958288-Settings) explains what Battery Saver does. Other than disabling the display when your device is downward, it doesn't seem to have any other purpose.

> **Battery Saver**
>
> Toggles the battery life optimization feature. Battery Saver disables the display while the device is pointed downward. Pokémon GO will continue to track distance traveled and notify you of nearby Pokémon while Battery Saver is activated.

Comment: Does it actually disable the screen? For me, it just turns black with backlight still on and with visible status bar and software buttons. I assume it just stops rendering.

Comment: The display goes all black (except for the game's logo), which might help reduce power consumption for certain displays. It also prevents you from pressing any of the buttons in the game while it is, say, sitting in your pocket. It is still technically "on" though. If you have software buttons for back/home/recents, those will still be active as well, unfortunately.

Comment: I expect stopping the rendering process could make a fairly significant difference to the game's battery usage, mind.

Comment: Sometimes I've run into an issue on iPhone where the battery saver works in reverse. The screen dims when the phone is pointed upward and only turns back on when it's pointed downward.

Comment: @me_and The CPU being busy rendering is fine. It's a big battery-drainer, but nothing compared to simply *having the LED backlight on*

Comment: Do anyone else has the issue of game sometimes becoming unresponsive after being restored from battery saver though? I had to disable it because of that.

Comment: **UPDATE:** June 30 Update removed Battery Saver

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 I heard the Battery Saver was remove, although it wasn't in the release notes of the latest update. I have the latest update and the battery save is still visible for me.

Comment: @Wondercricket. It seems that its still visible on Android, but on iOS its away. A bit mysterious.

Answer (score 8):

On some Android devices it turns the screen off when the phone is in your pocket. That doesn't work on other devices (and iOS doesn't let apps do that!) so it dims the screen if possible and stops rendering graphics.

Answer (score 0):

What the battery saver mode does is that it forces your phone to enter a low-power state mode whenever you hold your cell phone in an upside-down position, so that the app consumes fewer system resources while you are walking around which in turn saves a significant amount of battery power. 
[Source](https://bestforandroid.com/battery-saver-mode-pokemon-go/)